# Do you need to get a new IDP when you get a new driver's license endorsement?

Tags: driving, driving-licenses, motorcycles

A few months ago, I got an International Driving Permit. Then, last month, I got a new endorsement on my California driver's license (M1 endorsement for driving motorcycles)

Can I now legally drive motorcycles overseas with my existing IDP? Or do I need to get a new IDP to reflect my new endorsement before that's legal?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your IDP is simply a translation of your existing license into several languages, with the classes of vehicles you can drive endorsed by a stamp. You'll notice that your existing IDP only has the stamp on class B (passenger cars), and does not have the stamp on class A (motorcycles), so it does not indicate that you can drive motorcycles. To be sure, you should get it replaced.